# Why does sshd accept local network inbound connections and refuse external inbound connection?

Tags: ssh, networking

When I try to connect to my server from the internet, I always get:

```
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: connect to address XX.XX.XX.69 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host XX.XX.XX.69 port 22: Connection refused
```

But from the local area network with `192.168....` all works fine.

Why this difference?

*Note* I tested with `telnet XX.XX.XX.69`. Port 22 is open.

Comment: What is in the auth.log (or similar). You might want to make ssh server more verbose while trouble shooting.

Comment: What is the contents of the files `/etc/hosts.deny` and `/etc/hosts.allow`? Please update your question with the results. What do you see when telnetting from remote location into your box on port 22? Same for local telnet.

Comment: the both .deny and .allow are empty

Comment: Did you put some allow/disallow-rules into the sshd_config? Is there a local firewall active?

Comment: from local and from remote location telnet XX.22 say the same OpenSSH ... bla-bla
It is strange but just now **my ssh works!!!**. Nothing changed but i tryed to conect by other way from local network to my external IP and get: The authenticity of host 'XX.XX.XX.69 (XX.XX.XX.69)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is ....04:b4:da.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? y
Please type 'yes' or 'no': yes
Warning: Permanently added ' ' (RSA) to the list of known hosts
So it work now. All solved without config enchantments

Comment: May be an previously established local tunnel prevent from establish a new ssh connection?

Answer (score 1):

“Connection refused” indicates that there is a firewall preventing connections or that there is no server listening on that port on the target host. A few possible reasons why your telnet attempt would have worked but not your ssh attempt:

- The SSH daemon was not running when you tried with ssh.
- You didn't try telnet and ssh from the same machine, and SSH connections are accepted from the machine you ran ssh on but not from the machine you ran telnet.
- The SSH server requires [port knocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking). The telnet attempt happened soon enough after the port knocking, but the knock's validity had expired when you tried ssh.
- The IP address of the server is dynamic and was assigned to another machine at the time.
- Something about the network configuration changed between your attempts. Most likely on your router, but possibly on your client machine, on the server or any place in between. It's difficult to speculate without having more information about your network setup.